# import.sql is very slow when invoking large number of insert statements

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

i am using **import.sql** to create **demo data**, when the **import.sql** file is getting bigger with insert statements, it's execution becomes very slow, and it takes long time to process, is there's any way to make it faster ?
i am using **mysql-essential-5.1.47** with **hibernate 3.5.1-Final**
please advise, thanks.

Comment: How is this file "executed"? How is Hibernate relevant to this question? WHat does this file contain and why and when do you execute it?

Comment: @JBNizet, i am using the hibernate property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` and i have the import.sql file on classpath which hibernate invokes when running the application.

Comment: is that can be optimized through batch insert and caching configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, this feature should only be used for quick'n dirty prototypes. If you're using it each time you start your application, then simply don't. Import the file once and for all, and then start and stop the application as many times as you want. If the schema or data changes, then reimport it explicitely.

If you're using it for unit tests, then also create the schema once and for all, and use [dbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) to import data before each unit test. But the data used by the unit test should be reduced to the minimum necessary for this specific unit test.

Comment: can you please add reference for DBUnit.